# Does module.exports have to be defined when require()-ing a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, require, babeljs

I'm using Babel to transpile my ES6 files on the fly on an Express server.  In my `server.js` file (vanilla JS), I put `require('babel-core/register')` and `require('./app')`.

In `app.js` (ES6), I do all my normal Express stuff stuff:

```
import express from 'express';

let app = express();
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});
... etc
```

Even though I don't formally define `module.exports` in my `app.js` file, when I run `node server`, `app.js` gets correctly `required` and runs.  Why does this work?

Comment: [`module.exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) and [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_alias) are already define by Node.js, assigned an empty object. You're not required to modify it or replace it unless you want to expose a value to other modules.

Comment: I never exposed `app` of `app.js` via `module.exports`, yet it's still imported into `server.js` - I'm interested as to why this is happening.  (especially if `module.exports` is supposed to be empty)

Comment: Are you able to reference `app` in `server.js`, allowing you to define additional routes outside of `app.js` – `require('./app').get('/foo', ...);`? The module, regardless of what you do, still exports something; though, it may not be the `express()` application you created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you require a module, the code inside that module will be executed, but it is executed only once. Subsequent `require` calls to the same module will have no effect except to return whatever the module exports. [That's the nature of node modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (look for the note on 'caching'). By using `module.exports`  you are basically designating a return value for it.

You don't need to export anything in your case, the `app.listen` line is called as soon as you require app.js. Although you could export an API or something like this if you wanted to:

```
/*app.js*/

import express from 'express';

let app = express();

module.exports = {
    start:function(){
        app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
    })
}

/*server.js*/
require('babel-core/register');

var app = require('./app');

app.start();
```

I might be misunderstanding the question, but I don't think babel and express are relevant really.

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't sure if Babel was setting module.exports as it transpiled, that's why I added the tag.